# How is OS X Deployment Target presented to the end user?

Tags: xcode, macos

The build setting **OS X Deployment Target** in Mac OS X specify which minimum OS X version that is required to run the application.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html):

> This identifies the earliest OS version on which your software can run. By default, Xcode sets this to the version of the OS corresponding to the base SDK version and later.

**If the end user tries to install and run the application on a lower version of Mac OS X than the Deployment Target, how is this presented to the end user?**

Basically I want to know if the deployment target can be used to prevent users with out of date from using the application in a user friendly way, so they don't just get an "ERROR: CAN'T START" in their face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deployment target isn't presented to the end user, but there is an Info.plist key [`LSMinimumSystemVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) that tells users when their OS is too old.

Answer (score 1):

On the latest versions of macOS, the user will see two things when his version of macOS is too old for a specific app:

1. The app icon has a cross overlay.
2. When the user starts the app, a message will be presented explaining that a newer version of OS X/macOS is needed to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the hard way that **OS X Deployment Target** is not preventing the user from starting the application at all, even though they have a too old version of OS X.